# laravel mass assignment setting not working

Tags: php, security, laravel, mass-assignment

When I insert user information into my app I use the following code:

```
$userId = Auth::user()->user_id;

$newUserInfo = UserInfo::create([
            'u_info_id' => $userId,
            'u_first_name' => Input::get('u_first_name'),
            'u_last_name' => Input::get('u_last_name'),
            'u_phone_number' => Input::get('u_phone_number'),
            'u_address' => Input::get('u_address'),
            'u_state_id' => Input::get('u_state_id'),
            'u_city_id' => Input::get('u_city_id'),
            'u_zip' => Input::get('u_zip')
        ]);
```

But I cant do this `'u_info_id' => $userId` since that will force me to make **u_info_id** fillable for the mass assignment.

So my problem is, how can I use `'u_info_id' => $userId` without making **u_info_id** fillable for mass assignment. I dont want users to be able to edit **u_info_id**. That field should be inserted backend.

OR, do I only need to set fillable mass assignment when using laravel **->fill()** ?

Comment: What does your UserInfo model look like?

Answer (score 0):

I solved it like this:

**//Validation of inputs**

```
$newUserInfo = new UserInfo();

        $newUserInfo->u_info_id = $userId;
        $newUserInfo->u_first_name = Input::get('u_first_name');
        $newUserInfo->u_last_name = Input::get('u_last_name');
        $newUserInfo->u_phone_number = Input::get('u_phone_number');
        $newUserInfo->u_address = Input::get('u_address');
        $newUserInfo->u_state_id = Input::get('u_state_id');
        $newUserInfo->u_city_id = Input::get('u_city_id');
        $newUserInfo->u_zip = Input::get('u_zip');

        $newUserInfo->save();
```

Comment: You could've also updated your question with your UserInfo model. I'm certain it's because said model does not have the `$fillable` variable.

Comment: My model (used) to have "u_info_id" as fillable. Now it doesnt. u_info_id is also primay key, with incrementing set as FALSE @RichardA